# How much time does it take for an audit export job to finish?

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-email-audit-api

I have a job scheduled several days ago and the status is still Pending. Is there any way to known how much time approximately one needs to wait? Or find a queue position to estimate the progress yourself?

Request ID is 505334862.

Thanks,
Dennis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about the Google Email Audit API, I don't think there is a way to check the progress.  The only thing you can do is to retrieve status of a request to see if it is completed.

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-audit/#retrieving_status_of_a_request_for_a_user_accounts_information

Comment: Hmm, I was afraid that checking status is the only thing to do... Thanks.